# Start loop foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code:

```
<?php
        foreach ($cars as $i => $car){
           echo '<option>'.$i.'('.$car.')</option>';
        }
    ?>
```

How to do that this foreach start with number 400?

Comment: a for-loop is more useful for such a task. It's very good documented ;-)

Comment: Reading the official documentation before asking could help: [for loops](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) - [foreach loops](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Do you have over 400 cars in that array?

Comment: `$from400cars = array_slice($cars,399,count($cars));` before your loop.

Comment: Yes, I have 400 name cars in this array. I want that first get option in this format: car(400), next: car(401)

Answer (score 2):

If you really have over 400 cars in that array you can do this:

```
for($i=400; $i < count($cars); $i++){
    echo '<option>'.$i.'('.$cars[$i].')</option>';
}
```

Comment: Note to @NinjaMaker: depending on how you structured your array, you might want to set `$i=399;`

Comment: And then add one on your output to make it say 400!

Comment: Slightly off-topic optimisation - if you take the `count()` out of the `for` loop it should perform much faster if the `$cars` array is large.